# Google Drive PHP method listFiles and get return 'thumbnailLink' NULL

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm using the PHP V2 API. I requested full access (scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive). I also tried adding all of the different scopes to no avail.

I'm fully able to retrieve all files and list them but the thumbnail link is always null. Same with 'hasThumbnail'.

I tried the API explorer on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples and it shows me the thumbnail links correctly.

The relevant code can be boiled down to this:

```
 $drive =  new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);;
 $files = $drive->files->listFiles($parameters)->files;
```

This is the response from the API explorer.
[image]

The response from my code (for the same ID) is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. It took 5 hours to run into this such simple solution.
Not many fields show by default, you must specify which fields you want populated.

The modified basic query now is:

```
   $this->drive->files->listFiles([
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(thumbnailLink, webViewLink)'
    ])->files;
```